# Criar um executável

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .exe

Bom dia, eu fiz uma aplicação em C# recentemente mas ainda só está na forma de código e precisava de criar um executável ! Mas nunca fiz isso, não sei como fazer.
Alguém pode ajudar ? Obrigado !

Comment: Você quer dizer compilar pela linha de comando? Algo do tipo `csc.exe nomedoarquivo.cs`

Comment: Para ser sincero não sei, eu nao tenho a certeza. Eu criei esta aplicação no estágio e agora pediram-me para criar e um executável da minha aplicação para testar

Comment: Bem, para conseguir ajuda efetiva é importante que a comunidade entenda e consiga reproduzir seu problema. É a melhor maneira de conseguir uma resposta que te ajude. Compilar um arquivo `.cs` por linha de comando é diferente de construir um projeto no Visual Studio por exemplo. Eu construiria um exemplo representado aquilo que você está tentando fazer e editaria a pergunta. Quanto mais detalhes relevantes melhor. Dê uma olhada em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: É tão simples como: eu tenho o meu projeto no visual studio 2015, um código escrito em C# e quero criar um executável para ele. Só isto

Comment: Se é isso, basta clicar em "Compilar Solução" no menu do Visual Studio. Dê uma lida na documentação da MSDN: [Criando e limpando projetos e soluções no Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5tdasz7h.aspx). Se você selecionou o tipo correto de projeto um executável será criado.

Answer (score 3):

Clique em build -> publish

Uma tela aparecerá para você configurar como será feita a instalação no PC do cliente, configure da forma que te atenda e publique. Será criado um Setup, um Manifest e uma pasta com o nome Application files onde você configurou a saída. No PC do cliente é só você executar a forma de instalação que você configurou e seu programa será instalado automaticamente.

Se você precisa apenas do executável, pode também consegui-lo na pasta visualStudio20XX -> Projects ->  ->  -> bin -> release, mas ao executá-lo ele não será instalado

Answer (score 1):

Compile seu projeto no visual studio:

BUILD > BUILD SOLUTION ou Tecla de atalho, F6

o Executável será gerado na pasta:

[Pasta do seu projeto]\bin\Debug